Validating argument at specific mocked method call index? PHPunit/Mockery
So a very simple test: a method persisting some objects gets an array of data.
class A
{
    public function __construct(private BucketRepository $repository){}

    public function saveObjects(array $data)
    {
        foreach ($data as $row) {
            $this->repository->persist(new Bucket($data['amount']));
        }
        $this->repository->flush();
    }
}

How would I test that all calls of the 'persist' method are called with the right Bucket object?
In my test code I'd have something like this
public function testSaveObjects()
{
    $mock = $this->createMock(BucketRepository::class);
    $subject = new A($mock);

    // Something here to check it correctly
    $mock->expects($this->exactly(3))
    ->method('persist')
    ->with(....)

    $subject->saveObjects([
    [
        'amount' => 2
    ],
    [
        'amount' => 6
    ],
    [
        'amount' => 9
    ]
    ];
}

How do I assert that at the first call, the Bucket has an amount of 2, and at the second an amount of 6. I'd need to somehow get the actual argument object of the call at the n-th index and then verify it. But I see no way to do it in either PHPUnit or Mockery.
PHPunit used to have the at matcher, which was literally perfect but that is deprecated and unavailable now in newer versions.

Below is the test with which you can test whether the values are the argument step by step. The callback is called each time persist() is called.
I have added the getAmount() method to get the amount. You may have a different method. Of course you could also have a collection of bucket objects via $amountsExpected and test with that.
Bucket
class Bucket
{
    private int $amount;

    public function __construct(int $amount)
    {
        $this->amount = $amount;
    }

    public function getAmount(): int
    {
        return $this->amount;
    }
}

TEST
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class ATest extends TestCase
{
    public function testSaveObjects(): void
    {
        $amountsExpected = new \ArrayIterator([2, 6, 9]);

        $repository = $this->createMock(BucketRepository::class);
        $aService = new A($repository);
        $repository
            ->expects($this->exactly(3))
            ->method('persist')
            ->will($this->returnCallback(function($bucket) use (&$amountsExpected) {
                self::assertEquals($amountsExpected->current(), $bucket->getAmount());
                $amountsExpected->next();
            }));

        $aService->saveObjects([
            [
                'amount' => 2
            ],
            [
                'amount' => 6
            ],
            [
                'amount' => 9
            ]
        ]);
    }
}


+1, nice solution with ArrayIterator, you should be even able to drop the ampersand in use (&$amountsExpected) because of that.

Yes, that ampersand is not necessary. I think I used it because of a notice in PHPStorm. With the ampersand the hint is not displayed. I have just searched for the notice. This happens when you trust the IDE too much and do not think about it. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-71775/False-positive-for-Variable-is-only-used-inside-closure-inspection-for-variable-used-in-different-if-else-branches

Thanks for the link, upvoted. Sometimes those are really out of line, requires adding ignore comments but those can't always reasonably placed. Thanks for taking the time to explain.
